# Need to customize pagination arrows from angular mat-paginator (Replace it with other icons)

Tags: angular, angular-material

I need to replace the arrows icons present at angular mat-paginator because i need custom design. The link to mat-paginator is below.

https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/overview

Tried to look into: node_modules/@angular/material/paginator/ to find a way to change the icon but no luck

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by modifying these classes:

- `.mat-paginator-navigation-previous`
- `.mat-paginator-navigation-next`
- `.mat-paginator-icon > path`

1. First, set the **default arrow icon's** SVG path to `display: none`:

   ```
   // global level override
   .mat-paginator-icon > path {  display: none; }
   ```

   or

   ```
   //component level, using 'deep'
   /deep/ .mat-paginator-icon > path {  display: none; }
   ```
2. Use CSS to set the new icon:

   - using `background-image: url(...)`
   - use a clean SVG dataUrl, e.g. from an icon library like [remixicon.com](https://remixicon.com).
   - Example:

   ```
   /deep/ .mat-paginator-navigation-previous .mat-paginator-icon {
       background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 24 24' width='28' height='28'%3E%3Cpath fill='none' d='M0 0h24v24H0z'/%3E%3Cpath d='M16.172 11l-5.364-5.364 1.414-1.414L20 12l-7.778 7.778-1.414-1.414L16.172 13H4v-2z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
   }

   /deep/ .mat-paginator-navigation-next .mat-paginator-icon {
       background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 24 24' width='28' height='28'%3E%3Cpath fill='none' d='M0 0h24v24H0z'/%3E%3Cpath d='M16.172 11l-5.364-5.364 1.414-1.414L20 12l-7.778 7.778-1.414-1.414L16.172 13H4v-2z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
   }
   ```

   - You can adjust your svg width/height/viewbox to suite your needs.

[image: screenshot]